# Weird spacing of columns using @{} in latex

Tags: tables, formatting

This is my code:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{} c @{} c @{}}
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Target Firm}}\\
\hline
Assets & NPV \\
\hline
500 & 100 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

And this is my output:

[image: outpud]

I wan to remove the space on the sides and between the columns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to adjust the column separation in the `\multicolumn` as well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}c@{}}
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{\textbf{Target Firm}}\\
  \hline
  Assets & NPV \\
  \hline
  500 & 100 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]